# Bad JSFiddle configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React, and I am having issues with it. When ever I try to run my code I get alert saying that `"Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle"`.

Here is my React code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">

</div>

<script>
  var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return <div > Hello {
        this.props.name
      } < /div>;
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render( <
    Hello name = "World" / > ,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
</script>
```

I literally copy pasted it from Facebook JSFiddle baseline.

Can you help figure out what I am missing?

Comment: Those scripts only works if you fork the fiddle.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way I can use react on jsfiddle without using those scripts?

Comment: why don't you use the left panel to add those scripts

Comment: Take [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40qa7zmu/) and fork it.

Comment: And you can't change any setting either, have to be javascript 1.7 with no syntax highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JSX, Facebook is restricting the setting to JS 1.7 and you may need to use Babel to compile it to javascript.

With compiled script(JSX) link and Coffee script syntax, you can execute React code samples.

Try this working code: https://jsfiddle.net/9gnkLgex/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

<script>
  Hello = React.createClass(
    displayName: 'Hello',
    render: () ->
        React.createElement("div", null, "Hello ", this.props.name)
)

React.render(
    React.createElement(Hello, {name: "World"}),
    document.getElementById('container')
)
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work. I want to run this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znqLLdev/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=znqLLdev#fork